# Components are not updated after p:push

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, push

I have a ManagedBean to handle a list of Item, a scheduled thread is adding a new Item every 3 seconds and push the item to the client, after it notifies the page have to update the ui:repeat component to show the new Item.

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<h:head>
    <title>GG Well Trade</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <p:socket channel="/notify">
        <p:ajax event="message" update="content"/>
    </p:socket>

    <p:commandButton value="Start" actionListener="#{bean.start()}"/>

    <h:form id="content">
        <ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
            <p:outputLabel for="foo" value="#{item.label}" />
            <p:inputText id="foo" value="#{item.value}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Remove" actionListener="#{bean.remove(item)}" update="@form" />
            <br/>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Bean.class

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
@PushEndpoint("/notify")
public class Bean implements Serializable{

    private List<Item> items;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    public void start() {
        ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(()->add(),0,3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void add() {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setLabel("label " + items.size());
        items.add(item);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ ": label" + items.size() + " added.");
        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish("/notify", item);
    }

    @OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
    public Item onMessage(Item item){
        return item;
    }

    public void remove(Item item) {
        items.remove(item);
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

In the developer console (Chrome) requests are received but it won't update the form. What's wrong?

EDIT: every response looks like this in the dev console:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[-5528246304040933585:3098257791475168902]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

Comment: What if you put the push inside the form and wrap the repeat with a panel and update that panel?

Comment: Oh and your bean is requestscoped... will be empty on each ajax call.

Comment: Will pushing too much notifies cause lag/performance issues?

Comment: 'Too much' of everything causes problems, even money. The push itself can be sort of broadcast, so that will not directly cause problems if you don't push big content. But you could spread this by creating 'groups' and push to groups in sequence. But if your 'update' in the ajax call is big, it might become a problem too, so also optimize that. (But with poll it will even be a bigger problem)

Comment: And what is your pf version? You could also try to not update in the ajax event, but call a (javascript) `p:remoteCommand` and update from there. Makes no difference, but I remember it solving that way to since the update did not work for me either on push (there is no real ajax event)

Comment: 6.0, when I press continuosly the Remove button when my ScheduledThread keep pushing Items it generate little delays. Also when I close the Chrome tab takes a couple of seconds. BTW my sistem is not old.

Comment: Delay in closing Chrome is not related in my opinion

Comment: Can a scrollList dynamically updated in this same way?